# Admob Mediation with Other Network

Tags: admob

Can any body explain admob mediation with any other network in step by step. I had searched for lots of article but cannot understand easily, even admob's document is also find inproper.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[This documentation page](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation-networks) lists down the following for all the  admob supported ad networks:

- Documentation (step-by-step instructions for setup included in most)
- Compatible SDK
- Adapter
- Customer Support Mode

Check the documentation links for each network for detailed step-by-step instructions i.e. what you are looking for.